# In javascript, can an array be corrupted if array.push() and array.shift() fire asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, push, shift

In javascript, can an array be corrupted if array.push() and array.shift() fire asynchronously?

I am using an array to manage the tracking of user activity and time spent on a web page. These events are created asynchronously and are pushed onto an array.

The array is processed like a queue. The array[0] event is sent via HTTP POST to the host database for post processing. On success, the array is shifted.

Since array.push() and array.shift() are called asynchronously, does this have the potential to corrupt the array?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "corrupt"?

Comment: what do you mean? like deep vs shallow copy?

Comment: "Asynchronous" does not mean "at the same time", which is impossible in JS.

Comment: I don't know about corrupted but... the order of the functions could screw up your results. Consider an empty array. Consider doing both operations on an empty array. You `shift` first you don't get anything. You `shift` after a `push` you do get something. If you don't manage order deterministically you could get unexpected results.

Comment: They could go in a different order, depending how long the asynchronous activity takes before each `.push`. No, it won't corrupt the data.

Answer (score 5):

Since JavaScript is single threaded, there is no way two function calls can happen at the same time.

Remember that "asynchronous" is not to be confused with "parallel".

In JavaScript the various asynchronous bits of code run exclusively before they either terminate or hand-of to other bits of code. This is all part of the [JavaScript Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) that's used to drive everything.

Now you can end up in a situation where you have code that's making an assumption that something won't change and some other code goes and changes it, but that's not corruption per-se, that's just making faulty assumptions.

The big challenge when writing JavaScript code is not inadvertent corruption, as you might get with multi-threaded C++ code that runs off the rails, but *sequencing*, as in getting your operations to run in the correct order. This is where Promises and `async` functions help immensely.

If you need the `push()` to happen before the `shift()` you must use tools like Promises to ensure that they happen in the correct sequence.